# What happens if I connect a transformer in reverse?

Tags: transformer, high-voltage

I was thinking the other day. A transformer is just two coils, right? There is no polarisation or anything else fancy? The ratio of the number of windings on the input to the number of windings to the output reflects how many volts are outputted given the input?

So if I connect my 250V to 7.5V transformer to the mains in reverse, will I simply get 8.33KV? I assume so.

More practically, what will happen? From memory, the breakdown voltage of air is approx 1KV/cm. Doesn't this mean there would be all sorts of streamers between the transformer output terminals? What about between the windings themselves? Surely the thin layer of insulation around the transformer windings tightly wrapped doesn't insulate that much?

And say there are streamers between the 8KV outputs of the transformer. What then? Fire? Blown fuse?

Comment: If only I read this BEFORE I tried it. There was a very loud humming noise then a shower of sparks and the transformer was no more

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As Mr Banana says - magic smoke happens. Because ...

Energy is transferred in  transformer via a magnetic field. The field is produced by the amp-turns in the core (amps flowing x number of turns). Above a certain level the core cannot support any more amp turns and the core "saturates". What was an inductor with resistance to AC of far more than its resistance becomes mainly a resistor.

You'd get lots and lots and lots of amps in the case that you mentioned - so much so that if the fuse didn't get there first the transformer would DEFINITELY be destroyed.

The iron core in a transformer is usually operated on the part of its magnetic curve where it is beginning to saturate and get less efficient. This is to get as much use of the steel core as possible. They are run close enough to "the edge" that a transformer made to run on 60 Hz mains will get much warmer on 50 Hz mains at the **same** voltage as the cycles are 60/50 = 20% longer and the current in the winding gets that much longer to increase  and ...

So a SLIGHT overvoltage may work OK - say about 20% max. But 230/7.5 0 30+ times as much "will not work"! :-)

Comment: :) You made me smile

Answer (score 7):

<s>Just try it. Just kidding, don't.</s> Inductive reactance is the key. The 7.5 volt winding will smoke at 250 vac, might even spontaneously self-rapid disassemble.